telegram bot js, почему время от времени падает эта ошибка?
Пользуется около 30ти человек, в бота пишут текст, он ищет этот текст по базе, и выдает всю информацию по ней. Бывает работает неделями, а бывает несколько раз за день эта ошибка падает, я не могу понять в чем дело, помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
Ошибка
TelegramError: ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: message text is empty

Код:
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const db = require('./db.json');
const includes = require('lodash.includes');
const TOKEN = process.env.TELEGRAM_TOKEN || 'xxxxxxx';
const options = {
    polling: true
};
const bot = new TelegramBot(TOKEN, options);

/*
const users = 
const usersID = users.map((elem) => elem.userID)
*/

let result = ''
const searchResult = (dataBase, searchBsw) => {
    dataBase.forEach((obj, index) => {
        obj.bsw.forEach((bswNumber) => {
            if (bswNumber === searchBsw) {
                result =
                    `bsw: ${obj.bsw.join(', ')}

Номер: ${obj.boxNumber}
                           
Где: ${obj.address}
                             
Где: ${obj.placement}
                     
Куда: ${obj.access || 'Нет информации'}
                            
Тип: ${obj.keyType}`
            }
            if (dataBase.length - 1 === index && bswNumber !== searchBsw && result === '') {
                result = 'Ничего не найдено, убедитесь в корректности введенных данных. Пример: <code>xxxx</code>, <code>xxxx</code>, <code>xxxx</code>'
            }
        })

    })
}

bot.on('text', async msg => {
    try {

        if(msg.text === '/start') {
            await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `
Например введите: <code>xxxx</code>
`, {
                parse_mode: "HTML"
            })}

//        if (includes(usersID, msg.from.id)) {
            await searchResult(db, msg.text.toLowerCase())
            await bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, result, {parse_mode: "HTML"}).then(result = '')
//        }
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})

bot.on("polling_error", err => console.log(err.data.error.message));


Только логировать все запросы и смотреть, что происходит перед ошибкой

как логировать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1578637/2659
